# MapView works incorrect

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mapview

I have 2 Activities. In main Activity I start new Activity with MapView

```
Intent set = new Intent();
set.setClass(getApplicationContext(), OrderMap.class);
startActivity(set);
```

onCreate in MapView

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
```

But there is no Zoom Controls and it looks like View "freeze". I can't move map. What's wrong?

Comment: r u extending your activity with MapActivity in which you are using map?

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to your `MapView` widget in your layout.

Comment: I have this xml for my view <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mymapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="api Key"
    />

Comment: @Dima Svinarenko: Well, that certainly seems OK. Here is a sample project that definitely works that you can use for comparison: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk

Comment: Looks fine. As one of commenters pointed out, make sure you extend your activity from `MapActivity`.

Comment: @Xion yes, I extend my activity public class OrderMap extends MapActivity public class OrderMap extends MapActivity

Comment: In that case, is the map correctly displayed or do you see just a gray 'chessboard'? In the latter case that would be bad API key or certificate that does not match it.

Comment: Well, then I admit I'm at loss, especially if don't see ANR message. Maybe you explicitly manipulate input events and that causes the MapView to be not responsive?