# Android MapView in fragment freeze (not clickable or dragable) after initialisation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I want to show a MapView in a fragment. The map is shown as what I expected, but it seems it is only shown as a picture. I cannot drag to move camera or spread/pinch to zoom. I also tried to use SupportMapFragment in my fragment, but got the same result.

I have a NavigationView in my Activity. I do not think there's conflict on the touch event of NavigationView and MapView.

Anyone met this before?

**fragment**

```
public class CustomizedMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer here, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758081/mapview-works-incorrect

Comment: @DanielNugent I tried to set clickable to true, but it does not work

Comment: Did you implement `OnMapClickListener` ?

Comment: @MdSufiKhan I think to use basic features(view and zoom) , you do not need to implement OnMapClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [`UiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(boolean)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#scroll_pan_gestures), by using this you can scroll (pan) around the map by dragging the map with their finger.

Another way is configure these options when the map is created via XML attributes.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  map:cameraBearing="112.5"
  map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
  map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
  map:cameraTilt="30"
  map:cameraZoom="13"
  map:mapType="normal"
  map:uiCompass="false"
  map:uiRotateGestures="true"
  map:uiScrollGestures="false"
  map:uiTiltGestures="true"
  map:uiZoomControls="false"
  map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

But in order to use these custom attributes within your XML layout file, you must first add the following namespace declaration.

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#using_xml_attributes).